# Adding in app purchases to an Open Feint powered game

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, in-app-purchase, openfeint, mkstorekit

I am developing a game with `cocos2d-iphone` and I am going to add in app purchases.
AFAIK my options are `Open Feint X` and `MKStoreKit`.

I still don't get what's the benefit of using `Open Feint` over `MKStoreKit`. Why would someone pick `Open Feint`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding some logic to `MKStoreKit`.
You can get the code from [my fork](https://github.com/Macarse/MKStoreKit).

Answer (score 1):

Why would someone use **any** 3rd party library over Apple's?

I think the question is moot because OpenFeint added IAP as a service to their existing developers. Meaning developers who use OF primarily as a social platform. And anyone who likes to use an all-in-one solution, from FB, Twitter via Game Center right down to IAP. From what I understand MKStoreKit is just an IAP wrapper with no other features.

Comment: I just noticed that `OFX` also gives me a way to handle virtual currency while `MKStoreKit` doesn't.